# couchdb on docker: open console

Tags: docker, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am new to both dockers and couchdb.

I have a Linux box (let's call it A) on which I have docker installed. On this, I am running a container (lets called it docker1) on which I've installed couchdb.

I now need to open the couchdb console and open the views. I know I can normally do it by doing http://localhost:ip/, but in this case couchdb is installed on a docker container. I know we can access the container port from the docker container host. However, I need to access the couchdb instance running on a docker container (docker1) from the Windows PC from which I am accessing the Linux box A.

Is there a good way to access the console from the Windows PC?

If not, is there a way to access the couchdb view? I want to edit it so that there are multiple keys.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have GUI access to your Linux box (from your description, I'm guessing it's not just a VM hosted on the Windows box), and if you're using a recent build of CouchDB (and the default port), you should be able to administer your CouchDB databases from your Linux box by navigating to http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html in a browser.

If you only have command-line access to your Linux box, you should be able to access the same interface from your Windows box as long as the port (5984) is open and accessible to HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

execute this on the Linux host.

```
docker run -p 5984:5984 -d couchdb
```

Now you can connect from the Windows host by using the LAN ip of the Linux host and the port 5948.

Comment: Thanks! this worked...port 5984 on my Linux machine was already used, so used a different one and it worked.